# Creating a Cassandra UDF that will convert JSON fragment into a Cassandra map column type

Tags: java, arrays, cassandra, udf

I'm bringing in some data from a relational database into a Cassandra table where some of the data coming in will be a JSON list of id:value pairs that will initially be represented as a text type.   This string will be built dynamically on the source from the child relationships to a parent table to basically fold in all related child records into a single record.   I'd like to see if its possible to create a UDF that will cast this JSON list into a map type.   Is this even possible?   Does anyone have any examples of how to do this?

I tried searching for examples of UDFs to do this and could only find this site: https://fossies.org/linux/apache-cassandra/test/unit/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/validation/entities/UFTest.java.

Comment: What is your json structure ?

Comment: You can insert json directly through INSERT JSON https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertJSON.html

Comment: An example of the JSON structure is `'{"name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York”}’`.   I'm trying to do this after the data has already been inserted as I want to keep a copy as the JSON text coming from my source feed.   I might use a materialized view to render a version with the UDF querying the source dataset as it is fed from the source.   Let me know if this makes sense.